# How to replace <br /> fromTextBox

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I insert a value to my textbox I get a `<br />` tag when I press Enter to insert a line break. How should I remove the `<br />` tag and replace with a line break using jQuery.

```
$('#dbDocumentFooter').keyup(function(e){
    var TextToBeDisplayed = $(this).val();
    if(e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey)  {
        TextToBeDisplayed = $('#dbDocumentFooter').val().replace("\n", "<br />", "g")
        $('#dbDocumentFooter').val(TextToBeDisplayed);
    }    
});
```

Comment: Add a semicolon at the end of the first command!

Comment: <br>, <br/>, </br>

Answer (score 0):

Try this one https://jsfiddle.net/qa3q9w3r/

```
$('#dbDocumentFooter').keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey)  {
        e.target.value+="\n";
        e.preventDefault();
    }    
});
```